# How to get the arguments of a function call in LLVM?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I want to write an LLVM pass that'll extract the arguments of function calls. If the argument is a constant one, my objective is to recover what that constant is.

The IR looks like

```
%2 = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 512) #3
```

The LLVM pass looks like

```
bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    for (auto& B : F) {
        for (auto& I : B) {
            if(CallInst* call_inst = dyn_cast<CallInst>(&I)) {
                Function* fn = call_inst->getCalledFunction();
                StringRef fn_name = fn->getName();
                errs() << fn_name << " : " << call_inst->getArgOperand(0) << "\n";
                for(auto arg = fn->arg_begin(); arg != fn->arg_end(); ++arg) {
                    errs() << *arg << "\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If I run the pass through `opt`, it produces the following

```
malloc : 0x3df3f40
i64 %0
```

What does `0x3df3f40` represent? Instead of `i64` and `512`, why does it produce `i64` and `%0`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a pointer to [Value](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Value.html). Try `cast<>`ing it to `ConstantInt` and then calling [getValue()](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ConstantInt.html#af8dde13a97efce293a7b04daf1e208fb):

```
for(auto arg = fn->arg_begin(); arg != fn->arg_end(); ++arg) {
  if(auto* ci = dyn_cast<ConstantInt>(arg))
    errs() << ci->getValue() << "\n";
  errs() << *arg << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify? (Expecting more details)

Comment: @JithinPavithran Updated the answer with example code.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But for `call void @foo(i32** %4, i32** %5)`, it prints `i32** %arg1
i32** %arg2`. Why is it not `%4`?

Comment: Things starting with `%` are not constants, these are references to other expressions. Note the difference between `i32 %1` and `i32 1`.

Comment: How do I find "to which named variable does `%1` refer to?"

Comment: If you are using LLVM API, then the reference already points to an instruction. In your case (`call void @foo(i32** %4, i32** %5)`) you need to iterate over its `operand_values()` to get references to instructions corresponding to `%4` and `%5`.

Comment: If malloc is the called function, then the cast to ConstantInt can't really fail, and so the if statement in the answer is really redundant ...